# Identity Server 4 - Preserving Return Url/Redirect Ui

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-2.2

We've run into a problem with our IDSrv and IDSrv Clients where if we try to go to the client at something like https://clientapp.com/myaccount/manage?foo=bar, everything is lost when not already authenticated.

Redirection to Identity Server occurs, but the uri turns into https://clientapp.com/signin-oidc so when someone logs in, they will not go  to the originally requested location with any specified query params. They will just log into Identity Server.

If I had to guess, there must be something in the middleware configuration where we can specify how to handle this sort of thing, but I'm not understanding nor finding any specific information on how this is done.

Comment: What happens if you pass query string parameters to your identity server url? I.e:  https://ouridentityserver.com/signin-oidc?returnUrl=test .. Will it keep the query string parameters when returning to your application?

Comment: @BrunoFarias Apologies. The uri will change from `https://clientapp.com/myaccount/manage?foo=bar` (what the user entered) to `https://clientapp.com/signin-oidc` automatically.

Comment: @BrunoFarias  So presumably, the `.../connect/authorize` endpoint then takes that and redirects the user when it's done with it's internal work - but not sure how to essentially intercept that or tell it to keep what the original uri was

Comment: @netdev19 did you solve it?